# Large categories

Tags: category-theory

I'm learning theory category in class, and I learned that small categories are the categories for which the class of all the objects is a set.

I also learned that locally small categories are the categories for which the class of all objects is not necessarly a set, but for any object A and B of the category, the class of morphisms from A to B is a set.

Can anyone give me an example of a category who is "large", neither small nor locally small? I can't think of such a category!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3278/whats-a-reasonable-category-that-is-not-locally-small perhaps this is of interest to you.